# Manipulate one component instance from few places ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have one component instance which should be updated from different places.
How can I update the props of this component from few other components?

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent someValue={this.state.someValue} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class AdditionalComponent1 extends React.Component {
// I want to update 'someValue' in ChildComponent
}

class AdditionalComponent2 extends React.Component {
// I want to update 'someValue' in ChildComponent
}
```

I need to have only one instance of ChildComponent

Comment: Show us the relevant code please. Edit your question and add the code for the relevant components.

Comment: @Chris, I updated the description

Comment: Great! Where is `AdditionalComponent` in your app? Is it a child of `ParentComponent`? a sibling? in an other route (if you are using that)?

Comment: @Chris, AdditionalComponent has no relation to ParentComponent

Comment: Then you probably want to take a look at state management libraries, such as redux.

Comment: @Трубецкой You might not need redux, check the answer and link within.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, thanks
I read the info from your answer. And now I'm thinking that I don't need redux dependency. I can resolve this issue by implementing observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // I want to update 'someValue' in ChildComponent

You can't update `someValue` from *within* the `ChildComponent` because `someValue` was passed as props, and props should be considered read only from within the component that received them.

You can however inform somehow `ParentComponent` that you want to update `someValue` - and if `ParentComponent` updates `someValue` then `ChildComponent` will also receive new version of that (because `someValue` lives in state of `ParentComponent`).

If `AdditionalComponent1` have no "easy" hierarchical relationship with `ParentComponent` (e.g. sibling, child, etc.) than you could use observer pattern, where `ParentComponent` listens for interesting events and `AdditionalComponent1` publishes such events.

[More](https://www.andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/) info.

e.g. in `ParentComponent` listen to events and act:

..

```
comonentDidMount()
{
  // from "anywhere" in your app you can publish event and listen here
  ObserverPatt.listen("eventName", ()=>{
     this.setState({val:0})
  });

}
```

..

Comment: is it a good reason to introduce `redux` when you feel like you need to achieve what OP describes? so that you can have all your state there in the store and `AdditionalComponent1` and `AdditionalComponent2 ` can disptach actions to make changes in the store and `ChildComponent ` can subscribe to the store and receives updates? Does it make sense?

Comment: @margaretkru redux? did I mention it?

Comment: no, that is why I am asking your opinion about introducing `redux` in the described situation.

Comment: @margaretkru No I don't think so, check the article I linked.